# regex to separate numbers from comma delimited list

Tags: regex

I need a pure regex (no language) to separate the numbers of this input array:

```
L1,3,5,0,5,80,40,31,0,0,0,0,512,412,213,900
```

Issues:

1. The first field (`L1`) is fixed. The array will always start with `L1`.
2. The other fields will always be 0 or positive numbers.
3. But I need to acquire each data separately, so it would be:
   A regex for second data (number 3 in the example)
   A regex for third data (number 5 in the example)
   ....
   A regex for sixteenth data (number 900 in the example)

I tried this regex `[^;,]*` but it wasn't able to get each data separately.

Can anyone help me on this issue?

Comment: Could you help us understand why this needs to be pure regex? It isn't the best tool for this.

Comment: To get each field, you need a separate capture group

Comment: wouldn't `L?(\d+)` suffice, you'd probably get an array of matches depending upon the language you areusing

Comment: I had the same idea like dawg, alas this expression assumes that there are no more than 16 values. Is that number fixed or limited?

Comment: @mvw it´s a fixed expression

Comment: @JustinMorgan I´m using an automation software using ASCII serial input from serial COM port. Theres only the possibility to use a regex expression to acquire data, theres no possibility for scripting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to refine dawg's approach such that less capturing groups are used:

The fourth field can be matched by

```
^L1(?:,(\d+)){3}
```

[Online Test](https://regex101.com/r/xK9lE4/1)

The fifth field can be matched by

```
^L1(?:,(\d+)){4}
```

etc.

Answer (score 3):

With 'pure regex' to get each field, you have to use separate capture groups:

```
^L(\d),(\d+),(\d+),(\d+),(\d+),(\d+),(\d+),(\d+),(\d+),(\d+),(\d+),(\d+),(\d+),(\d+),(\d+),(\d+)$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oV0kT9/1)

(Note: In Python, Perl, Ruby, Java, etc you can have a global find and capture like `/(\d+)/g` but that is the language gathering up the matches into a list...)

---

If you want just one specific field, you can use numbered repetition.

```
^L(\d)(,(\d+)){N}
```

Capture group 3 would always be field `N-1` so to capture 213, the 15th field, in your example:

```
^L(\d)(,(\d+)){14}
```

[Demo2](https://regex101.com/r/oV0kT9/2)

Comment: I aprecciate your help but maybe I was not very clear. My issue is that I need a regex expression let´s say only to get the fourth column, for example. In your expression we are getting all the columns at the same time.

Comment: Well ive tried it but it captured a lot of groups besides the strict number at the column. I´ve tried ^L\d(,\d+){14} but it still gets the comma.. any way to throw that comma away?

Comment: You do not have the nested parenthesis `(,(\d+))` so yeah -- the comma would be part of the match. I also do not know the flavor or capabilities of the regex you are using to suggest something different.